# Go の interface の語尾に "-er" を付ける事が多いのはなぜ？

Tags: go

Goのinterfaceの語尾に"-er"を付けることが多い事に理由はあるのでょうか？

例えばStringメソッドを持つStringerはStringable等の名前では無いことに、Goの思想はあるのでしょうか？

Comment: [Effective Go: clarify interface naming conventions](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/5421)

Comment: 言語の開発チームが明文化してるんですね。
しかし、なぜ"-er"等なのかの理由は書かれていませんね。

Answer (score 6, accepted):

格納するデータの役割(Role)を明示する為ですが、golang では一般的に役割に er を付ける事が多いです。
例えば Read 出来て、Close も出来るのであれば ReadCloser となります。
ちなみに

http://www.carlopescio.com/2011/04/your-coding-conventions-are-hurting-you.html

この記事に

- the -er suffix
- the -able suffix
- the -Object suffix
- the I- prefix

について書かれていますが、-able については当てつけっぽく実際何をやるのかが分かりづらい、-Object は MarshalByObject 等の様にバッティングの可能性がある、I- は List が IList じゃないのに矛盾してるよね、といった事が書かれています。

Comment: interface名が明示しているものは、そのinterfaceの役割であって、
interfaceを満たしたデータ自体が、そのinterface名が示しているものではないという認識であっていますか？

Comment: 僕個人の認識では「データがどの様な役割を持っているかを示す目的として er が使われている」と思っています。
だからこそダッグタイプの意味がありますし、タイプアサーションにも意味をなしますし、ReadCloser という名前から開発者が簡単に「Read や Close が出来る」と一目で分かるメリットがあると思っています。例えば -able が一般的な java だと intreface の多重継承は出来ないので、抽象的な名前を付けざるを得ないですが、golang だとそもそも継承などしなくてよいので、Read() 関数を作ればそれは Reader だし、Write() を作れば ReadWriter だという事になります。

Answer (score 0):

Javaだとよく-ableを使いますが、別言語ですので、それにあまりひっぱられ過ぎないほうがよいと思います。

コメントにもあります通り

- [doc: Effective Go: clarify interface naming conventions · Issue #5421 · golang/go](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/5421)

> Clarifying that proper English agent nouns are preferred would be helpful.

と下記参考になると思います。

- [Interface naming convention -er vs. -or - Google Groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/Golang-Nuts/8xnggK1wo0U/7TF01pO3D6AJ)

> Proper English is always preferable.

> Also, the convention is to use -er for interfaces with just a
> single method, not for all interfaces, and it works best when
> the method name is a verb. You take the method name and
> add -er to form a noun.

- [単語力アップ！語尾に「able」を付けると？ | オンライン英会話ガイド](http://xn--eckaqj0mnhrcc5850eyl2fqira.com/phrase/intermediate/able.html)

> まず、「〇〇able」とする事ができる動詞として、先ほど紹介したように“動詞”が挙げられるのですが、その動詞の中でも「他動詞」にしか語尾に「able」を付ける事ができません。

> 次に、「able」を語尾に付ける事ができる物として「名詞」がありますが、例えば「結婚」と言う意味を持つ「marriage」の語尾に「able」を付け加えて「marriageable」とすると、「婚期に達した、年ごろの」と言う意味の「形容詞」になります。

### まとめ

ableは動詞では**他動詞**につけるものです。
-erをつけるほうが、ableをつけるより自然な英語になる場面が多いのではないでしょうか。
また-erは**名詞化**するのに使われているようです。 -ableだと形容詞化してしまうのかな。